# "Import All New Photos" in Photos.app imports duplicates

Tags: photos, photos.app, import

When I click "Import All New Photos" from my iPhone 7 in Photos.app, it imports all the pictures but doesn't seem to recognize it's done so. After clicking back to the iPhone tab, the photos that were imported are still marked as "New Photos", rather than "Already imported".

The pictures that aren't recognized as "already imported" seem to be "live" and they show up like this when import them.

### Example Live Photo

[image: live photo]

Could "live" have something to do with them not being recognized as already existing in my library.

I have "Copy items to the Photos library" turned **on** in my Photos.app settings
I'm running iOS 11.1.2 and photos 2.0 on my MacBook Pro Retina w/ MacOS Sierra 10.12.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Repairing my Photos.app Library fixed the issue! Photos/videos that I've imported now show up as "Already Imported" instead of as "New Photos".

### The Solution

> Hold ⌥-⌘ (Option-Command) while launching Photos.app

You will be prompted to repair your library. Proceed to do so.

**Note:** It is highly recommended to back up your library first in case the repair process corrupts it.

[Source](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7426266?start=0&tstart=0) (Apple Forums Q&A)